# How can I check what was installed for an apt package?

Tags: apt, package-management

I just installed the package autojump through apt and now I have no idea how to actually use it. Newer versions uses a `j` alias, but apparently the apt version does not.

In interest of finding out which binaries I should execute to use autojump, **is there a way to see what exactly was installed by package?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following command will list all files installed by the package `autojump`:

```
dpkg -L autojump
```

It is a `dpkg` command because dpkg is actually responsible for installing packages, apt just a frontend that runs dpkg.

For completeness, there is also the reverse command:

```
dpkg -S file
```

This will give you all packages which contain something named `file` (this can also be a single part of a path).

Comment: Woohoo! I've been using `apt-file`for ages and can't believe I didn't know about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you just installed a package with apt, the downloaded .deb file is still in /var/cache/apt/archives/

You can open the file with file-roller and you'll see which files and folders are added to the filesystem. For the executable it's usually in usr/bin/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

install `apt-file`

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apt-file -y
```

use it this way

```
apt-file show packageName
```

Comment: This is useful for packages which are not installed, but not necessary for installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

Once a package is installed, its archive file is stored locally in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

To examine the contents of a `deb` file stored there, use the following command:

```
dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/package-name.deb
```

> Note that this method will only work for packages that have been
>   installed recently.
>   If the package cache has been emptied since you
>   installed the said package, this method logically won't work.

---

For example, in my case, this is what the command outputs for the `toilet`package:

```
# dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/toilet_0.2-1_i386.deb
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     14096 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/bin/toilet
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1559 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/man/man1/toilet.1.gz
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       164 2010-02-08 20:03 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/README
-rw-r--r-- root/root       174 2010-02-08 20:03 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/TODO
-rw-r--r-- root/root       708 2006-11-15 22:11 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/copyright
-rw-r--r-- root/root      9601 2010-02-08 20:22 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/changelog.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       346 2010-02-08 19:50 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/NEWS.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       428 2010-02-08 20:34 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/changelog.Debian.gz
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/bin/figlet-toilet -> toilet
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/man/man1/figlet-toilet.1.gz -> toilet.1.gz
```

---

If you wish to exclude directories from the output, simply append `| grep -v "^d"` to the end of the command.

```
# dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/toilet_0.2-1_i386.deb | grep -v "^d"
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     14096 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/bin/toilet
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1559 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/man/man1/toilet.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       164 2010-02-08 20:03 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/README
-rw-r--r-- root/root       174 2010-02-08 20:03 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/TODO
-rw-r--r-- root/root       708 2006-11-15 22:11 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/copyright
-rw-r--r-- root/root      9601 2010-02-08 20:22 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/changelog.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       346 2010-02-08 19:50 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/NEWS.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       428 2010-02-08 20:34 ./usr/share/doc/toilet/changelog.Debian.gz
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/bin/figlet-toilet -> toilet
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2010-05-12 18:21 ./usr/share/man/man1/figlet-toilet.1.gz -> toilet.1.gz
```

Comment: the cache of apt is just a cache, who can ensure you that you will find your package in the cache? You have to guess.

Comment: Well, I was assuming the OP wanted to find out the info not long after installing the package.

Comment: I was, but I would note in your answer that this only works for recently install packages. BTW I did upvote you, thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Ok! The downvote was kind of harsh if you ask me, though.